# Coldfusion - error when making SOAP request to Neolane

Tags: soap, coldfusion, cfhttp, neolane

I am trying to make webservice SOAP requests to Neolane using Coldfusion and CFHTTP.

I have copied the SOAP request directly from Neolane's documentation, so I think that is okay.

The error message returned is :

SOAP-ENV:ClientLe message XML SOAP est incorrect (service '', méthode 'POST').Le nom de méthode 'ExecuteQuery' du paquet SOAP ne correspond pas à celui du paramètre 'action' de l'en-tête 'Content-Type' ('')

which translates to :

SOAP-ENV: clientle SOAP XML message is incorrect (service'' method 'POST'). The method name 'ExecuteQuery' SOAP package does not match the parameter 'action' in the header 'Content-type '('')

Is the action parameter in the Content-type header set by Coldfusion in the CFHTTP?
Is there something that should be added with cfhttpparam?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Gary

Update: Found solution.  Needed to add SOAPAction using cfhttpparam and use an alternative authentication method that was different from the example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.  Needed to add SOAPAction using cfhttpparam and use an alternative authentication method that was different from the example in the documentation.